# ML-AGENTS tensorflow model not running in inference mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, ml-agent

I am working on Ml-agents and training jet to fly towards target. Training is completed and now i am trying to run my model in inference mode.
getting this error.

ArgumentException: Off-axis dimensions must match Barracuda.TensorExtensions.Concat (Barracuda.TensorShape[] shapes, System.Int32 axis)

i am using python 3.6, ML-AGENTS v0.7, Unity 2017

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In player settings under define scripting symbols, write ENABLE_BARRACUDA;